# HttpClient not sending cookies

Tags: java, cookies

I'm trying to use the Reddit API (https://github.com/reddit/reddit - www.reddit.com/dev).

Here is my `HttpClientHelper`:

```
public HttpClientHelper(String path)
{
    this.url = "www.reddit.com";
    this.path = path;

    if(httpClient == null)
    {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}

public void addParamForGet(String key, String value)
{
    dataGet.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
}

public void addParamForPost(String key, String value)
{
    dataPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
}

public HttpResponse executePost()
{
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        uri = URIUtils.createURI(METHOD, url, PORT, path,
                dataGet == null ? null : URLEncodedUtils.format(dataGet, "UTF-8"), null);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataPost, HTTP.UTF_8));

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

public HttpResponse executeGet()
{
    try {
        uri = URIUtils.createURI(METHOD, url, PORT, path,
                dataGet == null ? null : URLEncodedUtils.format(dataGet, "UTF-8"), null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

When I try to login on Reddit, it works:

```
    HttpClientHelper client = new HttpClientHelper(Endpoints.User.login);

    client.addParamForPost("api_type", "json");
    client.addParamForPost("user", username);
    client.addParamForPost("passwd", password);
    client.addParamForPost("rem", String.valueOf(true));

    client.executePost();
```

Result: `{"json":{"data":{"cookie":"30310021,2014-10-27T16:02:27,300937022ed465f695747a2aa7fd**********","need_https":false,"modhash":"9ch7btilr85ce7c2a427ef87bdb422132f738c3a1**********"},"errors":[]}}`

Here are the cookies returned (overshadowed):

```
    List<Cookie> cookies = client.getHttpClient().getCookieStore().getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("", cookies.get(i).toString());
    }

    [version: 0][name: __cfduid][value: d****7d2bfa753ef32b2f2861c117b8c141444******][domain: .reddit.com][path: /][expiry: Mon Dec 23 23:50:00 GMT 2019]
    [version: 0][name: reddit_session][value: 30310021%2C2014-10-27T15%3A18%3A39%2C5**08054f8fa07d82aa0ac027a2f**********][domain: reddit.com][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 31 23:59:57 GMT 2037]
```

On the following request to retrieve the user data `/api/me.json`, it fails:

```
    HttpClientHelper client = new HttpClientHelper(Endpoints.User.me);
    client.executeGet();
```

Result: `{}`

But, when I print the cookies, the result are the same (this is expected, as I use the same instance of DefaultHttpClient):

```
    List<Cookie> cookies = client.getHttpClient().getCookieStore().getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("", cookies.get(i).toString());
    }

    [version: 0][name: __cfduid][value: d****7d2bfa753ef32b2f2861c117b8c141444******][domain: .reddit.com][path: /][expiry: Mon Dec 23 23:50:00 GMT 2019]
    [version: 0][name: reddit_session][value: 30310021%2C2014-10-27T15%3A18%3A39%2C5**08054f8fa07d82aa0ac027a2f**********][domain: reddit.com][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 31 23:59:57 GMT 2037]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but...

You didn't indicate the nature of the failure on retrieving user data.

One thing I observe is that the reddit_session cookie has a domain of 'reddit.com', whereas the other has domain '.reddit.com'. The former would only be sent back to the server when you use 'reddit.com as opposed to 'www.reddit.com', whereas the latter would be sent for all sub-domains. Perhaps this was the cause of the failure.

I am puzzled that you got those cookies back though if you were in fact using a domain of 'www.reddit.com' for the original request.